# How do I remove the option to open a separate window for a menu?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am attempting to create a simple text editor and I have added some simple menu features. 
When I create a menu with Tkinter, there seems to be a default option to open the menu in a new window.

The options that appears: [image: The option that appears]

What the window looks like: [image: What the window looks like]

Does anyone know of any way to remove this, I am using Python 3.

This is the bit that could be the problem:

```
#Menu options
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
fileMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
fileMenu.add_command(label="New", command=newFile)
fileMenu.add_command(label="Open", command=openFile)
fileMenu.add_command(label="Save", command=saveFile)
fileMenu.add_command(label="Find", command=findInFile)
fileMenu.add_command(label="Print")
fileMenu.add_separator()
fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=exitRoot)

helpMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Help")
menu.add_cascade(label="About", command=about)

textArea.pack()
```

The full code can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/nfvkt1yE)

Comment: Change to `fileMenu = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=0)`